# Add custom field on augmented Apache log parsing with Grok in Logstash

Tags: apache, logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

here is my problem : Let's say I have some standard Apache logs, like so :

```
IP1 IP2 - - [13/Jun/2016:14:45:05 +0200] "GET /page/requested.html HTTP/1.1" 200 4860 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
```

I can sucessfully parse these logs with my actual configuration of Logstash :

```
input {
    file {
        path => '/home/user/logsDir/*'
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But on these logs, I apply some machine learning algorithm and I give them a `score`. So the new log line looks like that :

```
IP1 IP2 - - [13/Jun/2016:14:45:05 +0200] "GET /page/requested.html HTTP/1.1" 200 4860 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0" 0.00950628507703
```

*Note the* `0.00950628507703` *at the end of the line, which is the actual* `score`

Now, I would like to parse this line so I could use `score` for visualisation in Kibana (Logstash is integeated in the whole ELK stack ). So it would be great if the score could be parse as a float.

**NB:** I can place the score before or after the standard Apache log message and insert any kind of characters between the two (currently it is just a space).

Any idea on how to tackle this problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found how to process. I add a little keyword before the score : the word `pred`

So my lines are know like this :

```
IP1 IP2 - - [13/Jun/2016:14:45:05 +0200] "GET /page/requested.html HTTP/1.1" 200 4860 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0" pred:0.00950628507703
```

And I use this configuration for logstash :

```
input {
    file {
        path => '/home/user/logsDir/*'
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG} pred:%{NUMBER:prediction_score}"}
    }
# I convert the score into a float in order to vizualise it in Kibana
     mutate {
        convert => {"prediction_score" => "float"}
     }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I hope this will help you if you are stuck with the same problem !

Cheers !